# Twilio Verify called from Twilio Functions returns resource not found

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am making a simple to the verify api from a Twilio Function triggered in a studio flow.

The error I am recieving is "verifications resource not found".

I assumed it was an authentication issue, but I have the correct SIDS and have checked that a number of times.

Not sure what I am missing.

```
const accountSid = process.env.ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
const functions = Runtime.getFunctions();
const formatPhone = require(functions['formatters/formatPhone'].path);

exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  const verifyPhone = formatPhone.toSearch(event.verifyPhone);
  const verifyType = event.verifyType;

  client.verify
    .services('<Verify SID>')
    .verifications.create({ to: '+1' + verifyPhone, channel: verifyType })
    .then((verification) => {
      console.log(verification.sid);
      callback(null, 'done');
    })
    .catch((err) => callback(err, null));
};
```

I can run this code from my machine and hit it from studio using NGROK and an http widget instead of a function.

SAME CODE.

I feel that it may be the work of Legacy Systems!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as strange as it sounds it ended up being a library versioning issue.

```
npm i 'twilio'
```

and then pushed again to the server

```
twilio serverless:deploy --override-existing-project
```

I also realize that I didn't list the error originally. I have edited it to make more sense as to the problem I was having.

Comment: Twilio Functions, by default, uses an older version of the Twilio Node Helper library. Verify is a newer feature which shows up in a later version of the Twilio helper lirbary.

Comment: Hey, I work on the serverless toolkit (`twilio serverless`), and if you upgrade to the latest version and create a new project (`twilio serverless:init`) it should now install the latest `twilio` package with it and you should no longer have these problems. Sorry you had to discover this and find out the issue yourself, but I'm glad you did get it sorted.

Comment: Thank you both for the info

Comment: You can make sure that you use the correct version of Twilio Node Helper Libraries consistently across your project dependencies.

You can set this https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/dependencies either via the `Serverless Toolkit` (package.json) OR on your `Twilio Console` under `Settings --> Dependencies` of that particular Function.